# htaccess rewrite url with same get parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite the url using .htaccess  
Here is my main url which will be accessed by public:
`http://example.com/watch?v=123456789`
I want same values of get parameters but in new location:
`http://example.com/index.php?v=123456789`
How can i do this? Help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it could be something like.. (.htaccess at root level)

```
RewriteRule ^watch/?$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The important thing is the QSA option ("QueryString Append")

Hope it helps!

Comment: @starkeen, I don't think that your correction is.. correct. Because the slash isn't provided in the original example (despite of the optional question mark).. At the most, it could be something like `RewriteRule ^watch(.php)?$ index.php [QSA,L]`. Adding the slash would mean that _watch_ could be a directory

Comment: The slash is optional there so that the rule can accept both `/watch` and `/watch/` . Also if the `watch` is an existent dir then the rule won't match the pattern unless you spacify a traling slash to the directory path.